# Calling a django APi in React shopping Cart

Tags: django, reactjs

I have built a react shopping Cart application which has a login page Signup Page Products Add to Cart and other features like Checkout through Api . Now the other person from my team has build a backend api on django. I want to call that api from my react code now. How should I do it? Do I need to learn something specific? I have searched in internet and all of the sources we to make serve react and django from same project. I have a React project with me and a separate api developed by someone else. Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make an HTTP request to the API your colleague made. This video explains three methods you can use really well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4K33w-0-p2c

- XMLHttpRequest
- fetch() API
- Axios. Here the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qM4G1Ai2ZpE) from the same channel.

You should use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) because it gives you the simplest way to make these requests:

```
// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```